# how to compile Android 2.3.4 source code and get .img file

Tags: android, android-source

I'm using Android ARM board from TECHNEXION, I have Android 2.3.4 source code.

- How can I compile and get `.img` file?

Answer (score 0):

Whether the code from TechNexion, from TI or from the project Rowboat, they are all about the same.

You can find the general instructions to build there: http://code.google.com/p/rowboat/wiki/ConfigureAndBuild

Don't worry about the part on getting the source, but you'll need to change the names of TARGET_PRODUCT or things like that.

That won't give you .img but at least the file systems and enough to get started.